# Shapefile with multiple shapes but only one polygon

Tags: r, gis, polygon, shapefile

I am using the "King County with Natural Shoreline for Puget Sound and Lake Washington" shapefile from http://www5.kingcounty.gov/gisdataportal/.  The outline for Lake Washington appears when I plot the shapefile but is not saved as an additional polygon relative to the outline of King County.  I wish to color Lake Washington a different color to the rest of the county but am not sure how to do this because the shapefile only has 1 feature.  I am trying to manipulate the shapefile in R.

Comment: Post some code. This is a coding website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the "hole" that is Lake Washington and then add that to the plot. This uses base graphics but it's just as easy with ggplot.

```
library(rgdal)

# your shapefile
kc <- readOGR("kingsh/kingsh.shp", "kingsh")

# extract the singular hole that is Lake Washington and
# make it into something plottable
lw <- SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(kc@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[2]]), ID="lw")))

plot(kc, col="steelblue")
plot(lw, col="maroon", add=TRUE)
```

[image]

You can find the hole by manually scanning the objects or something like:

```
unlist(lapply(kc@polygons, function(p) {
  polys <- slot(p, "Polygons")
  lapply(polys, function(q) {
    slot(q, "hole")
  })
}))
```

I had to guess at how you're reading it in since you didn't provide any code.